# Port a nextjs application into a php site

Tags: php, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I have a nextjs app that I'm using to process stripe payments that I've deployed to Vercel. The app is simply a form with tons of functionality built in but requires the use of an api (which is why I'm using nextjs). What is the best way to get this into a php site? I need to access the nextjs api in order to communicate with stripe. Otherwise I would have just built the react app in the php site and rendered it on the page in question per usual. I've never done this before, so please any recommendations would be huge.

Here are the options I've come up with:

1. iframe. I've never been a huge fan of these, but figured this was an option. I can render my app via iframe on the php site.
2. use the vercel deployed nextjs app strictly for the api and build the react form into the php site. Then I would simply change the api requests to point to the vercel deployed nextjs app instead of a local api.

Are there better more efficient methods?

Comment: Why do you need php, what do you want to achieve? Why do you need the nextjs in your PHP?

Comment: Its an existing site that we need stripe integration with. I already have a nextjs stripe form built and tested, so I was wondering if there was a way to port it into a php site. We're really just trying to avoid rebuilding the wheel if we can. Right now I'm testing an iframe solution, that is, using an iframe on the php site to render the nextjs form. It's so-so in that its responsive, but it creates other hurdles we need to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Try [vercel-php](https://github.com/juicyfx/vercel-php), a PHP runtime for Vercel. Using the configuration described in the README, you can use a PHP repository as your backend and fetch data from there for your NextJS app.

Alternatively, you can use this directly in your NextJS repository and instead of having the api folder inside the pages directory, just have it as a top-level directory